# When and how should I use `const` and `immutable` in D?

Tags: d, immutability, const-correctness

In many modern languages `const` correctness should be used to clarify interfaces and intent as well as to provide some opportunities to the compiler to optimize. In D there's the cool feature of really immutable data. How should `const` and `immutable` be used? I kinda figured, that preferring `const` as qualifiers for functions arguments and `immutable` for local variables seems to be a good way to write code, but as soon as you want to assign a struct with a reference or pointer like data member (private or not) to an immutable variable you can't do that.

```
struct S {
    private int[] data;
}

void main() {
    immutable s = new S; // won't work, since members aren't immutable
}
```

Hence, changing the implementation of a `struct` can break my code, if I use immutable. Should I prefer `const` for local variables and use immutable only when necessary? What are the guidelines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are extremely lucky - a video from DConf2013 with presentation devoted exactly to this topic has been published last week : http://youtu.be/mPr2UspS0fE

In your case, `auto s = new immutable(S)();` should do the trick. You can then create data slice points to in constructor. However, if this slice may point to *any* data, then S can't possibly be immutable, because both `const` and `immutable` are transitive in D - they provide very strong guarantees not only about variable itself but also about any data that can be accessed from it indirectly via reference/pointer.

It is actually covered in linked video, but short summary is that you want to use immutable when really intend to. In other words, when you **want** your code to break if `S` implementation changes so that immutable guarantees are no longer valid.